# Loading Nodejs Module at runtime in electron app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

Currently I am playing around with `electron` using `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` along side a simple vue project. This is the project https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder .

```sh
   vue create my-project
   cd my-project
   vue add electron-builder
   npm run electron:serve
```

My goal is to add a simple plugin-like architecture. The app serves only base functionality but can be extended with "plugins". Those plugins therefore are not included in the built, but will be loaded at runtime by electron. I would prefere when those plugins just behave like node modules ( `module.exports =` ) with its own dependencies ( probably with a package.json file inside ). I would locate those plugins at `app.getPath('userData') + '/Plugins`.

I looked at a few approaches on how to tackle this problem :

---

### 1. Using Nodejs `vm` module

First, I tried using Nodejs `vm` module to read and execute a script from an external file, all at runtime. It works great so far, although I would not be able to use external dependencies inside those loaded scripts. If I want to use external dependencies inside the plugin scripts, those dependencies must have been included in the electron build beforehand. Somehow defeats the whole purpose of having plugins ... only vanilla js + nodejs base modules would be possible .

---

### 2. using `global.require`

I saw this solution in another SO answer.

- [Using node require with Electron and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339866/using-node-require-with-electron-and-webpack/37349344#37349344)
- [Webpack/electron require dynamic module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342888/webpack-electron-require-dynamic-module)

They say to use `global.require` but it throws an error saying `global.require is not a function`. The solution looked promising first, but somehow I can't get it to work.

---

### 3. simply use `require`

Of course I had to try it. When I try to `require` an external module from a non-project location it won't find the module, even if the path is correct. Again, the path I am trying to locate the module should be at `app.getPath("userData")`, not in the projects root directory. When however, I locate the plugins inside the root directory of the project it gets included in the built. This again defeats the purpose of having plugins.

---

### Goal

So far, I haven't found a viable solution to this. I simply want my electron app to be extendible with basic node modules at runtime ( following a pre-defined schema to simplify ) . Of course there is `atom`, made with electron, using their own `apm` manager to install and load plugins, but this seems way to overpowered. Its enough for me to only have plugin files located locally, to have a public "marketplace" is no goal. Also, it's ok if the app has to reload / restart to load plugins.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After more and more research I stumbled over 2 packages :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-plugin-manager
- https://github.com/getstation/electron-package-manager

both integrating `npm` to programmatically handle package installation at runtime. I settled for `live-plugin-manager` for now since its better documented and even allow package installation from local file system.

### Pro

I was able to integrate the system out-of-the-box into a vanilla electron app. Works like a charm.

### Cons

<strike>.I was not able to use it inside a `vue electron` boilerplate (like the one I said I was using in OP), since webpack is interferring with the `require` environment. But there sure is a solution to this.</strike>

**Update** : I was able to get it to work eventually inside a webpack bundled electron vue boilerplate. I accidentally mixed `import` and `require` . The following code works for me using `live-plugin-manager`

```js
// plugin-loader.js
const path = require('path');
const { PluginManager } = require('live-plugin-manager');
const pluginInstallFolder = path.resolve(app.getPath('userData'), '.plugins');
const pluginManager = new PluginManager();

module.exports = async (pkg) => {
  // installs pkg from npm
  await pluginManager.install(pkg);
  const package = pluginManager.require(pkg);
  return package
}
```

```js
// main.js
const pluginLoader = require('./plugin-loader');
pluginLoader("moment").then((moment) => {
   console.log(moment().format());
})
```

This will install "moment" package from npm during runtime into a local directory and load it into the app, without bundling it into the executable files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work! After an hour of googling I'm very happy to have found your post! Good luck with your app.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I am very happy with my findings as well

Comment: Your post was very helpful indeed. The live-plugin-manager is really cool!