# Trying to use global.require in Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing as this post:
[Using node require with Electron and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339866/using-node-require-with-electron-and-webpack)

Basically, I need Electron to read other js files that weren't together in the build.
But when using **global.require**, I'm getting the following error:

****webpack_require**.g.require is not a function**

I can use require(module) normally, but not global.require(module)

My code in App.js:

```
var comp = (global.require('../../plugins/' + plugin).default);
alert(Object.keys(comp));
```

Any idea?

Comment: any updates on the issue ?